# typescript npm module source-maps not working in create-react-app

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, source-maps

I have written a npm module with typescript. I have set
`"sourceMap": true,
"module": "commonjs"`.
I use that module in create-react-app via `npm link`.
When I want to debug the npm module the source-maps are not recognized.
How can I get it working ?